# How can I uninstall WPS Office for Linux?

Tags: 12.10, software-uninstall, wps-office

I have installed WPS office from the OMG Ubuntu website but it kept crashing, and is in Chinese. In the Software Center, there is an option to reinstall, not remove. Is there any way I can remove it?

Comment: You can install WPS using snap now. It is in English and things seems to work properly.

Answer (score 10):

WPS Office is Chinese software intended to be used in Chinese.

[Ubuntu Kylin](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuKylin), a new official Ubuntu flavor intended for users in China, includes "cooperation with WPS", so presumably WPS will not crash when used with Kylin.

The current version of [WPS](http://www.wps.cn/) is actually Windows software. The [Linux version of WPS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/wps-office-for-linux-looks-like-microsoft-office-but-isnt) at OMG Ubuntu is still in Beta, so some crashes are to be expected.

If the Software Center is not offering an uninstall option, you should be able to use Synaptic or the command line to uninstall: `sudo apt-get purge wps-office`.

Comment: The latest version (alpha 10) provides official English support, add many new features and fix many bugs. You can download it [here](http://wdl.cache.ijinshan.com/wps/download/Linux/unstable/kingsoft-office_9.1.0.4032~a10_i386.deb).

Answer (score 9):

You can remove WPS Office/Kingsoft Office by follow commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge wps-office   # for a8 or earlier versions.
sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office  # for a9 or later versions.
```

BTW: Kingsoft office is full English support, and stable enough now? Do you want try it again?

You can get newer version here: http://wps-community.org/download.html

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it using `sudo apt-get remove wps-office` or `sudo apt-get remove "name of package"`.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following to know the installed components

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep wps
```

you will get something like

```
libwps-0.4-4:amd64              install
```

then just uninstall the above package by entering

```
sudo apt-get remove "package name"
```

for given output it would be

```
sudo apt-get remove libwps-0.4-4:amd64
```

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

`sudo snap remove wps-office` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely remove the apps and its data you can type the command like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove wps-office
```